# Selenium: Chrome doesn't maximize under IIS

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, selenium-chromedriver

I have a web API application. When I call some URL, selenium starts and goes to some site and makes screenshots and saves them to files.
When I run code in Visual Studio by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, the application works well.

But after I'd publish my application to IIS, I noticed that browser doesn't maximize and I got small screenshots.

I use a chrome driver, because IE driver and Firefox driver throw error
 `unable to connect`.

I tried this code:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions()
{

};
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions)) 
{
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
       /*driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1040); this doesn't work too*/
```

I notice when selenium starts under IIS I don't see a browser window. I only see a process of chrome in the task manager.

How to make maximize window of a browser under IIS?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @Siddharood As far as I remember I created screenshot, then I scrolled and created screenshot again etc, and then I merged two screenshot to one.

Comment: Do you use RemoteWebDriver?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
```

Can you try :

```
chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
```

And remove :

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Comment: There are no errors. The application makes screenshots and saves them into files. But resolution of screenshots is smaller than my screen. There are scrollbars in screenshots.